# Create a long Sum using the C++ api of Z3?

Tags: c++, api, z3, smt

What would be the preferred way to create a long Sum with a variable number of `int`s?

My guess is something like this:

```
expr mk_add(expr_vector args) {
    vector<Z3_ast> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)args.size(); i++)
        arr.push_back(args[i]);
    return to_expr(args.ctx(), Z3_mk_add(args.ctx(), arr.size(), &arr[0]));
}
```

Is this Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct. Just remember to be careful with `Z3_ast` objects as their reference counts are not updated automatically (here `to_expr` should take care of that).

Another solution that stays within the C++ API and doesn't need awkward translations is this:

```
expr mk_add(expr_vector args) {
    expr r = args[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < (int)args.size(); i++)
        r = to_expr(args.ctx(), r + args[i]);
    return r;
}
```